# AG-Grid | Page is unresponsive when screen was left for an hour or longer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid (version 6.0.1) with AngularjS (version 1.2.6). In my case, grid is updated after 4seconds. It's observed that when screen was left for an hour or longer, page gets unresponsive and then its crashed.

```
//update grid data
$scope.gridOptions.api.setFloatingTopRowData([rootNode]);
$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(agData);
```

Any help what can be the reason?

Comment: I think your issue is more with javascript rather than just ag-grid. Seems like there may be some scripts that are continually running from your 4-second polling function

Comment: Is there any way to diagnose the problem area? I have tried with chrome profiling but didn't get any useful information

Comment: You can use the timeline tab, it's very similar to the profiling, but it shows it all in a more graphical sense that seems to give more useful info. Also look into the network tab, I am guessing that you are using some sort of ajax calls since you are updating every 4 secs... finally if you update your question to show how (setTimeout, setInterval, some other method) you are updating every 4 secs we could help some more.